# Что такое форк в BitBucket?

Tags: bitbucket, git

При создании нового репозитория на BitBucket есть графа "Создать форк" и варианты: разрешить только приватные форки, разрешить форки, нет форков. Что такое форки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Форк - копия репозитория, которая создается для самостоятельного развития проекта, а также для выполнения пулл-реквестов (изменений сторонних разработчиков, которые они предлагают внести в "главный" репозиторий). При этом BitBucked/Github сохраняют информацию о родительском репозитории.

Answer (score 2):

Форк==fork, от английского "вилка". Ответвление проекта/репозитория. Обычно главную ветку зовут транк==trunk ("ствол") или main и от него идут ответвления бранч==branch или форк==fork.

В терминах разных VCS форк/бранч отличаются друг от друга. Например в `Git` под форком имеется ввиду любая разработка члена команды, которая как может слиться с основным стволом, так может и не слиться. В терминах `Subversion` форк это самостоятельная ветвь разработки, которая не сливается с основным репозиторием.

Поскольку речь идет о BitBucket - рискну предположить, что речь идет о `git`